# Form Submit taking to a new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, google-docs

I have a simple form. On submit (the submit action is a google docs form submission), it takes to a new page with focus on that page. I want to keep the focus on the current page.

What are my options?

This is the code (also present [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/c85tw/) )

```
<html><body>
    <form action="https://docs.google.com/a/rangde.org/spreadsheet/formResponse?formkey=dFlSZkt0TzZTWHJyblBiQlNrcmZvZGc6MQ" method="POST" id="ss-form" target="_blank" onsubmit="submitted=true;">
<br>
<input type="text" name="entry.0.single" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_0" placeholder="Your Name">
<br>
<input type="text" name="entry.1.single" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_1" placeholder="E-mail Address">
<br>
<input type="text" name="entry.2.single" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_2" placeholder="Pledge Amount">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I found a sweet solution to my problem here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351188/can-i-submit-form-info-to-google-spreadsheets-with-jquerys-ajax

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to do with the resulting form, (and if you're not comfortable relying js do all the lifting) you could also create a hidden iframe on the page, give it a name, and set the form target to the name of the iframe. This is only if you have no interest in having the user ever see the google page itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try AjaxForm, as found at http://jquery.malsup.com/form/, if you're using jQuery

Comment: This option looked very promising, but looks like google won't let me do so. These are the errors that were thrown: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)" and "XMLHttpRequest cannot load - Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Comment: Ah ok. It does come in very useful usually, but I guess only when the action's held on your own server (or doesn't have whatever Google has given it stops it from processing, perhaps). It's especially good when used with a callback to `slideUp()` the form and display a success message.

Answer (score 0):

A form's action parameter will always take you to that page.

Here is an example:
[POST without Form Method (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753589/post-without-form-method-php)